# Securing information from a retail POS system

Tags: encryption, public-key-encryption

I have created a back-end/processing/statistics for POS transactions for a retail store chain. The thing is, now it is time to move from alpha to beta, and we need some sort of safety for the incoming data. And this is where I am lost. How do I implement some resemblance of security in this kind of system?

What I have come up with is a simple asymetric key/value pair, that is unique for each POS system, where the server has all of the private keys, and each pos has the public part of this exchange. In addition to this, all of the data exchange is sent via HTTPS.

Does this kind of thing make sense? Or is there a better way to keep the data safe?

P.S. Since there is a need to reconfigure each POS seperately, that is in no way connected to this system, having to do manual work at each POS is not a problem.

Comment: Why exactly are you introducing the asymmetric keys, what are you looking to gain over simply using SSL?

Comment: @mikey so what you're saying is that there is no gain to be had with these keys? What I was thinking of was, that SSL was the transport layer protection, while the asymetric keys would provide some means of data layer protection. I may be wrong in this, but that is the way I see it. In terms of what gain would it make - maybe it is an overkill, but having a two layer protection seemed a good idea to me.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using asymmetric keys for encrypting your data layer (they are too slow).  Of course it cannot hurt to encrypt your data layer, but it may not be necessary.  The best way to figure out how to best secure your data is to first identify what you want to secure (what data is sensitive?) and what are the potential RISKS you are looking to mitigate?

Comment: @mikey I've got one last question. What if I'm trying to get rid of faked data? Since the API is in Public domain, anyone can try to mess up someone elses data. Keys would allow me to discern who has the access rights, and who doesnt. Or maybe in this case I should just go with some sort of tokens?

Comment: Right on!  IMO that is exactly the correct use for asymmetric keys in this case.  I'll elaborate in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd like to accomplish 2 things:

1) Encrypt the traffic so that it is hidden from outsiders (confidentiality).  You can accomplish this quite easily simply by enforcing that SSL is used for traffic between the client(s) and the server.  The server will require an x509 certificate to accomplish this.

2) Ensure that all traffic coming to the server originates from a trusted client/POS (integrity).  You can accomplish this using a couple of different techniques, both of which require an x509 certificate installed on each client (POS) system:

a) Require that all requests to the server be accompanied by *client certificates*.  In this scenario, the client (POS) has a x509 certificate installed, for which it is able to access its own private key (the server does not, and should not have this private key, it belongs to the client).  The server is configured to require client certificates with each request, it also is configured to validate that the client certificate presented does indeed match one of the POS systems.  So if you add a new POS later, you need to make a change to the server ensuring that it will consider the new POS cert valid.  Here is a description of the protocol for your own enrichment, you shouldn't need to know exactly how it works (because most tools IIS, Apache, etc. will abstract much of this for you) but it does demystify things a bit.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v5r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.itim.infocenter.doc%2Fcpt%2Fcpt_ic_security_ssl_authent2way.html

OR

b) Require that all requests to the server are *digitally signed* by trusted clients.  Public key (asymmetric) encryption allows you to sign a message.  Basically it is signed with the client's (POS) private key, and then anyone (including the server) can verify its integrity by validating the signature using the client's public key.  Many tools will actually encrypt and sign the message, which is OK, but if you're already using SSL and performance is a concern, you don't need to encrypt twice.  If security is more important than performance, encrypting twice can't hurt.  Here is some more info on digital signatures:  http://www.cgi.com/files/white-papers/cgi_whpr_35_pki_e.pdf

So you should have a pretty good plan of how to proceed.  Feel free to ask around here when you set out to implement these solutions, as there are a lot of things that usually don't work the first time around and debugging it is often difficult.  I do recommend a tool called Fiddler or WireShark, which can help debug web services to some extent.  Be sure that your client(s) can access their own private keys, and that the certificates of the clients are trusted by the server.  Good luck.

http://fiddler2.com/

Comment: Thanks mikey! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! I'll keep on asking around, if there are any difficulties.